# Convert 2D array to list of lists

Tags: multidimensional-array, f#

Is there a way to take a 2D array and get a list of lists. It seems like a simple operation, but I can't find a way to do it.
This code obviously doesn't work:

```
let arr = Array2D.create 4 4 0
let listOfLists = arr |> List.ofArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Array2D` (multi-dimensional array) and Jagged arrays (array of arrays) are two different types. You can see it from the type signatures:

```
let arr = Array2D.create 4 4 0 // int[,]
let arrJagged = toJagged arr // int [][]
```

If you neeed a multi-dimensional array I suggest you stick to it or use purpose build matrix library (like math.net). The `List` in F# is a singly linked immutable list, with some nice (easily create and recurse) and not so nice (performance) properties. AFAIK, there is no 2D List (there might be some appropriate data structure in an extended core library).

But you can easily convert your 2D Array into a list of arrays or list of lists, which is the equivalent of the Jagged array. It's a one liner:

`[for i in 0 .. 3 -> arr.[*,i] |> Array.toList]`

> val it : int list list =   [[0; 0; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 0; 0];
>   [0; 0; 0; 0]]

Or a bit more general:

```
let toListList arr = 
    [for x in 0 .. Array2D.length1 arr - 1 ->
        [ for y in 0 .. Array2D.length2 arr - 1 -> arr.[x, y] ]
    ]
```

> > toListList arr;;
> >     val it : int list list =   [[0; 0; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 0; 0]; [0; 0; 0; 0]]